# How to use onActivityForResult from one activity in another activity

Tags: android-studio, android-activity, kotlin

I am currently adding more features to a github project for my personal use. I need to create a list of applications to be shown in a grid view by either:
   1. Writing package name by myself (this functionality already existed) or
   2. Selecting from a list of apps (what i want to achieve) - all functionality is implemented in ChooserActivity using ChooserAdapter.

What would solve my problem is to pass information to the MainActivity and call its onActivityResult method, since there is a lot of things i cannot copy paste it. 
    For the clickListener (of each grid view item) I created the OnItemClickListener interface in ChooserAdapter and overriden it in the ChooserActivity.

ChooserActivity:

```
    class ChooserActivity : BaseActivity(), ChooserAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
private val backButton: FloatingActionButton by bindView(R.id.back_button_2)

override fun onItemClick(app: ApplicationInfo?) {
    val intent = EditorActivity.IntentBuilder(context)
            .build()
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
}


public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onActivityResult called ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    // !!!!!!
    MainActivity().onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent)
    //How can I write something similar to this to solve my problem?
}
```

ChooserAdapter:

```
    public class ChooserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChooserAdapter.ChooserHolder>{

private List<ApplicationInfo> listOfApps;
private Context mContext;
private PackageManager pm;
private OnItemClickListener listener;


public ChooserAdapter(@NonNull Context context, List<ApplicationInfo> list, OnItemClickListener l) {
    this.listOfApps = list;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.pm = context.getPackageManager();
    this.listener =
            new ChooserAdapter.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(ApplicationInfo app){
            try{
                Intent intent = (new EditorActivity.IntentBuilder(mContext)).build();
                ((ChooserActivity)mContext).startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
}

public class ChooserHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
     //stuff not useful to be shown
}}
```

The result of the above code resulted in not using the wanted MainActivity().onActivityResult(...), but the ChooserActivity's method.

Comment: Are you start `ChooserActivity` from `MainActivity`?

Comment: @StanislavBondar Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start `ChooserActivity` with `startActivityForResult()` from `MainActivity` and then pass result in this way `EditorActivity` -> `ChooserActivity` -> `MainActivity`

```
class ChooserActivity : BaseActivity(), ChooserAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
    ....
    public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "onActivityResult called ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
       setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
       finish()
    }
    ....
}
```

Override `onActivityResult(...)` in `MainActivity` and handle result

Comment: Didn't think of this simple and efficient way to call methods. It worked, thank you